# Deleting rows w. duplicate information while keeping first non-duplicated entry (and appending that row with data from duplicate entries)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset with 500k entries (rows). Each entry is for a particular student and contains information on the school the student 
went to that particular semester.

Because students stay at the same school for several semesters I have many entries for the same student and the same school 
(only the semesters change, i.e., EnrollmentBegin and EnrollmentEnd).

```
FirstName LastName CollegeName State PublicPrivate EnrollmentBegin EnrollmentEnd
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public         20050829      20051223
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public         20051229      20060113
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public         20051223      20060513
John      Doe    School B      IL       Private        20090105      20090301
John      Doe    School B      IL       Private        20090706      20090830
John      Doe    School B      IL       Private        20090831      20091025
Jane      Doe    School A      IL       Private        20100105      20100301
Jane      Doe    School A      IL       Private        20100706      20100830
Jane      Doe    School A      IL       Private        20100831      20101025
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public         20110829      20111223
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public         20120129      20120513
```

This means that for some students I have a lot of entries where student's name and college's name are the same.

I really just want the first instance of every new entry (i.e. whenever the school name changes for a given student) 
but I also need to know when the student's enrollment at that school ended.

This information is found in the LAST entry for each student for a given school. 
So I need to grab that value from the last entry and add to a new column in the row with the first entry for the student.

NB: I realized that some students, like John Doe above, go to School A, leave for another school, and then come back to School A. So ideally, to capture
that, I would like my final dataset to look like this:

```
FirstName LastName CollegeName State PublicPrivate EnrollmentBegin EnrollmentEnd EnrollmentEnd
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public      20050829      20051223      20060513
John      Doe    School A      NY       Public      20110829      20111223      20120513
John      Doe    School B      IL       Private     20090105      20090301      20091025
Jane      Doe    School A      IL       Private     20100105      20100301      20101025
```

How do I do this in the most efficient way? It seems like min and max can no longer solve this problem...

Comment: Hey akrun. No, I was just trying to make those values bold but I guess I still don't quite have the formatting down.

Comment: Looks like simple *group by min max* exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(EnrollmentBegin= EnrollmentBegin[1L], 
                   EnrollmentEnd=EnrollmentEnd[1L], 
                   EnrollmentEnd2= EnrollmentEnd[.N]) ,
   by =c(names(df1)[1:5])]
#   FirstName LastName CollegeName State PublicPrivate EnrollmentBegin
#1:      John      Doe    School A    NY        Public        20050829
#2:      John      Doe    School B    IL       Private        20090105
#3:      Jane      Doe    School A    IL       Private        20100105
#   EnrollmentEnd EnrollmentEnd2
#1:      20051223       20060513
#2:      20090301       20091025
#3:      20100301       20101025
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by_(.dots=names(df1)[1:5]) %>% 
  summarise(EnrollmentBegin=EnrollmentBegin[1L], 
            EnrollmentEnd1=EnrollmentEnd[1L],
            EnrollmentEnd2 = EnrollmentEnd[n()])
```

Comment: That did the job. I was thinking for loops, but you just saved me some time there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using base R's `lapply`

```
lst = unname(split(dat, dat[,1:5])[lapply(split(dat, dat[,1:5]), nrow) != 0])
out = do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, 
              function(x){x$EnrollmentEnd.new = x$EnrollmentEnd[nrow(x)]; x[1,]}))

#> out
#  FirstName LastName CollegeName State PublicPrivate EnrollmentBegin
#7      Jane      Doe    School_A    IL       Private        20100105
#4      John      Doe    School_B    IL       Private        20090105
#3      John      Doe    School_A    NY        Public        20050829
#  EnrollmentEnd EnrollmentEnd.new
#7      20100301          20101025
#4      20090301          20091025
#3      20051223          20060513
```

Comment: Another option would be `by`

Comment: When I try to use the unname command, I get the message: "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 129.4 Gb" and that is with only 500 rows. Why does that seem to be a problem?

Comment: @WykoW not quite sure, but i guess this could be because of multiple empty list elements after splitting. thanks for pointing it. I will try to fix this issue soon